# Show code coverage on Xtend files with jacoco

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, xtend

According to the following article: https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2016/01/12/code-coverage-for-xtend/
I'm able to generate coverage for Xtend with Jacoco and Maven, but SonarQube shows the coverage result on the generated Java source. However the line numbers and the markers of the coverage result belong to the Xtend file, so the coverage report becomes fake.

How can I tell the sonar plugin to use Xtend files on the coverage report view.

Comment: I think the problem is in the `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.JavaResourceLocator` for us.

Comment: Quoting contribution by user @HeinrichMueller, "Heinrich Müller" (just in case it gets deleted as a non-answer, because it seems to be a useful information update and they don't have the commenting privilege yet): Just for others searching for this site: https://dietrich-it.de/xtext/2016/01/12/code-coverage-for-xtend/

Comment: It's better to just update the dead link in the question (I just did) instead of commenting it. Comments are ephemeral an can also get deleted.